# 0.1 vs 0,1 in c++, why does neither result an error?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I come from a country where the way we write decimal numbers differs from the other place by whether I use ',' or '.' for decimal separator. Now this is why I by accident wrote somewhere in my c++ program:

```
while(true){
    long double x=0;
    //some code that increases the value of x 
    //by very small amount but it doesn't leave it at 0
    if(x>0,000001)break;
}
```

And this made the program run indefinitely. After wasting quite some time thinking my code was wrong I tried this:

```
while(true){
    long double x=0;
    //some code that increases the value of x 
    //by very small amount but it doesn't leave it at 0
    if(x>0.000001)break;
}
```

Which worked just fine. Later I understood my mistake (I used ',' instead of '.'), but now I am confused as to why doesn't the next code result with compilation error, and how come it's outcome is "greater"

```
long double g=0.001;
if(g>0,01)cout<<"greater";
else cout<<"smaller";
```

**Edit:** When I posted this question I didn't know that the comma is an operator. So the question was marked as duplicate and lead here [How does the Comma Operator work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work) .
But there I couldn't actually find a comparison between '.' and ',' .

Comment: Look up "comma operator"

Comment: Related: [How does the comma operator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work).

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thank you, but that is still harder to catch here. Using straight up values rather than variables.

Comment: You should enable your compiler's warnings.

Comment: actually , I think in all countries "digital" standard became to use period for fraction separator instead of comma for this exact reason. I'm from such country,Russia, myself and it started to change.

Comment: @Quentin not all compiler warn about this. Not all even warn about ; after if(). Also, not all people read warnings, but that's different issue :P

Comment: @MartinDinev: "*But there I couldn't actually find a comparison between '.' and ',' .*" You don't need one. You simply need to know that the comma doesn't mean what you think it means. Comparing the two is like comparing `if` with `+`; they're fundamentally different on every level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`,` in C++ is an operator which returns the value of its second operand. So `a, b` evaluates to `b`.

`,` also has very low precedence, so your comparisons are actually evaluated as:

`if((x>0), 01)` -> `if(01)` -> `if(true)`

Comment: comma allows to exploit for() because of this. Also allows to create fancy asserts or use  ternary operator in quite strange way. Not that I would appreciate to see that in code that wasn't made into a well-documented template or macro.